# Error while Querying HBase table from Apache Drill

Tags: hbase, hadoop2, apache-drill

SYSTEM ERROR: IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.()V from class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetaTableLocator

Facing above error while querying hbase table from apache drill in embedded mode.

Apache Drill version 1.14
Hbase version 1.4.8

Answer (score 0):

It is a known issue - [DRILL-4931](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-4931).

Could you try to build and run Drill 1.15.0-SNAPSHOT (master branch), whether [DRILL-6422](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-6422) solved this issue. 

If it doesn't help it means it is necessary to shade `hbase-client` in Drill.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried replacing the guava jar to earlier version 16.0 as mentioned in DRILL-4931 and it worked but I will try running new version 1.15 and check once.